# Использование canvas как буфера

Tags: gwt, java

Чтобы получить определенное значение мне периодически требуется рисовать на канвасе, а потом анализировать этот канвас попиксельно. При этом канвас никогда не вставляется в документ. Т.е. с ним работаю как с буфером. Каждый раз я создаю новый канвас (это бывает относительно не часто), и никак не показываю, что он мне больше не нужен. Верно ли такое использование `canvas` в веб-приложении и не будет ли утечек памяти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приходится порой использовать таким же образом. Вроде бы сильных проблем не замечено. В любом случае вы можете воспользоваться инструментами профайлинга в браузере  и поверить